# Write json object to file.json in assets using angular

Tags: json, angular

I am using angular to create an application and has a requirement to store a json object currently stored in a variable to file.json located in src/app/assets using angular.
I have searched a lot and have not found a way to do this.
Ask if need any more information.

Comment: So, are you trying to read and write the JSON file? I'm afraid you'll not be able to perform the write operation. That's how the browser works.

Comment: You can do it using nodejs writefile https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_filename_data_options_callback

Comment: @Ferhado not in the frontend (he is using Angular)

Comment: You are wright, not in frontend, I forgot about that, thanks!

Comment: @JoseGuzman file already exists in the assets folder i only need to update it or change the contents of it is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Not just using JS code. You'll need some backend logic to be able to do that.

Comment: @guzmanoj Can you let me know how to change content of assets folder file using backend logic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot write files with Angular. Don't forget that the Angular app is **not** running in the directory structure you create. It's not even running on a server. It's running in the browser as compiled JavaScript. It has no direct write access to any filesystem.

If you need to write to server-side files in your application, you need some server-side code. This can be achieved, for example, with NodeJS (Express, NestJS…) if you want to stick with JavaScript. Either way, you can't write files directly with Angular.